RPi 3 Model B not detecting input audio from Behringer Wing
I want my Raspberry PI model B to detect the audio output of a Behringer WING digital mixing table. I am using a powered USB hub to connect the USB-B to the USB-A port on the raspberry. But for some reason, it doesn't detect it. It may be a problem of power? I've already connected the usb hub to a power source. I've also installed pulseaudio ans alsa-utils.
Here's the output of arecord -l
root@raspberrypi:/home/amat# arecord -l
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****

And lsusb
root@raspberrypi:/home/amat# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 25a4:9311 USB C   USB C Video Adaptor      
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2109:2817 VIA Labs, Inc. USB2.0 Hub             
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) SMC9514 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

What am I missing?
